# Using interface types in implementations vs public interfaces

Tags: java, oop, interface

Is there a point to using interface types in implementations, or should you only use them as part of the public interface of a class or interface?

Example (Java):

```
public class SomeClass {
    // Declare list as..
    private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // or...
    private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // Does it matter which way list is declared if it's part
    // of the private implementation?

    // This parameter should be the most general interface type
    // allowed because it's public-facing.
    public void someMethod(List<Object> list) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you be as generic as practical. Prefer a Collection where possible, but some Collection(s) are ordered (and you may need that guarantee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining them as abstract as possible, you're hiding implementation details. Should you ever wish to use a different subclass from `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList<T>`, then you can do so without breaking code everywhere.

Always make it as abstract as possible while still having the methods available that you need. That way your implementation is as flexible as possible.

For example, I am a person with a pet. Right now I have a cat, but what if I get on a vacation to Africa and happen to see a very awesome elephant? My cat will starve because nobody gave her food and I will put the elephant in my pocket back to Belgium. If I were to define it as a cat, I would have to change my entire class. Instead, I define it as an animal.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    Animal pet;
    // Getters & Setters + Constructor
}

public abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() { super("Cat")); }
}

public class Elephant extends Animal {
    public Elephant() { super("Elephant")); }
}

public class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion() { super("Lion")); }
}
```

So when I make a new Person:

```
Person bestPersonInTheWorld = new Person();
bestPersonInTheWorld.setName("Jeroen");
bestPersonInTheWorld.setPet(new Cat());
```

I can simply kill the cat

```
bestPersonInTheWorld.dontFeedForTwoWeeks();
```

And I put my Elephant in the yard:

```
bestPersonInTheWorld.setPet(new Elephant());
```

Nothing has to be changed when it comes to implementation.

Comment: No animals were harmed in the making of this post.